# OpenCV 2.4.13 error: ‘Moments’ in namespace ‘cv’ does not name a type

Tags: c++, opencv, codeblocks

I'm a beginner in using OpenCV and I get this error when I try to compile my main.cpp-file (among many other errors):

[image]

[image]

I do not know what I'm doing wrong here. I downloaded OpenCV 2.4.13 zip-file, extracted it into my project folder (see the image) and included the cv.h-file into my main.cpp. What do I need to do? What causes this problem?

I'm using **Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, Codeblocks 13.12**.

Comment: From your description what you did it doesn't seem that you build OpenCV, [see here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html#linux-installation).

Comment: Thank you for your help! I will do the steps and get back to you =)

Comment: And please don't post pictures that have to be enlarged to be readable, instead copy code and error messages and paste it as code.

Comment: Okay, sorry about that. I thought it would help get better picture of the problem, when you see the folder contents etc. =) By the way the building worked! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error messages, you are mixing the local OpenCV instance headers (`/home/jjepoh/Document/codeblocks_workspace/opencv/opencv-2.4.13/include/opencv`) with the system-wide instance (`/usr/local/include/opencv2/`).

The system-wide instance is probably a different version, and because the local instance most likely uses "`#include <opencv/xxx.h>`" for inclusion of dependent headers, the system-wide location is selected in preference. So at the end you get a mixture of two different versions of OpenCV, which apparently doesn't work.

There are basically two (or three) possibilities to fix:

1. Install the new version system-wide.
2. Remove the different system-wide version (probably an opencv devel package).
3. Not use the new version and use the system-wide version installed in the system.

Comment: Thank you for your help!